# javascript alter variable definition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have draggable divs. Divs representing text from textarea that i am rearanging using array.

- **`[1] [2] [3] [4]`**

when i move divs after last div i am getting error about variable that tells what element on the right.

- **`[2] [3] [4] [1] rightElement is undefined`**

---

```
rightElement = $(".tile").eq($(".tile").index($(element)) + 1);
rightElementNumber = rightElement.attr("id");
rightElementNumber = rightElementNumber.replace(/id/, "");
```

I tried to create if else structure on undefined event, but sadly this event returnes regularly.

```
if (typeof rightElementNumber === "undefined") {
}
```

basically if i difine my var as `rightElement = $(".tile").eq($(".tile").index($(element)) + 0);` code will work as expected.
But i can't find a way to alter var definition.

Also i am assigning ".first" and ".last" class to first and last element, but because it's array. Left element of first index and right element of last index is the same thing.

Any ideas on how to alter rightElement definition depending on weither it's last element or not?

Comment: can you provide a working example?

Comment: I tried but failed because easier example required absolutly differen approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command checks if undefined type is undefined or anything else.

```
jQuery.type(rightElement.attr("id")) === "undefined"
```

When event undefined returnes regularly it has type "string" for element in the middle, and type "undefined" when it's on the right side.